# What does the parent tag in Maven pom represent?

Tags: maven, directory, pom.xml, artifact, parent-pom

E.g.:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>mycompany.trade.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany.trade.</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Does it mean that Maven will search for parent pom?
If yes, where, in which order? May be in folder up 1 level? Or in local repository or in repo?

Comment: It bears mentioning somewhere that the `parent` tag is optional. Setting it to something arbitrary may be mostly harmless, but may also have unintended side-effects later. E.g. SonarCloud.io assumes you want to link to parent site.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Yes, maven reads the parent POM from your local repository (or proxies like [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)) and creates an 'effective POM' by merging the information from parent and module POM.

See also [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

One reason to use a parent is that you have a central place to store information about versions
of artifacts, compiler-settings etc. that should be used in all modules.

Answer (score 22):

The common dependencies,Properties,constants etc can be definded in central parent project pom.xml

The main important thing is the parent project cannot be distributed and it looks quite similar to a regular "pom.xml" except that it also has a **packaging** tag

```
    <groupId>com.company.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenInheritance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

The child now able to inherit this using

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>MavenInheritance</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 15):

As the name suggests, we can point out a `parent pom.xml` file for the `current pom.xml` file. Doing so, dependencies, properties, constants and many more defined at the parent pom.xml file also get merged with the current pom.xml (child pom.xml) file. Say you have a parent tag in your projects pom.xml that looks like below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Then maven reads that parent POM from your local repository (or from repository managers like `sonatype`, `jfrog`, etc that you have configured) and creates a `Resultant POM` by combining the parent POM and your module’s POM.

To see the combined result use the following `mvn` command:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Comment: What do tags in `parent` tag means?

Answer (score 0):

This is the practice that is used in multi-modules projects where we need to inherit the dependencies from the parent projects.